# Subversion equivalent of "git add ."?

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I'm switching to subversion from git but I found that "svn add ." doesn't do the same as git.

It prints

```
svn: warning: W150002: '/home/mike/Projects/repos' is already under version control
svn: E200009: Could not add all targets because some targets are already versioned
svn: E200009: Illegal target for the requested operation
```

Does SVN have an equivalent? Or I must add them manually?

Comment: http://steveko.wordpress.com/2012/02/24/10-things-i-hate-about-git/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use commit:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.ref.svn.c.commit.html

Comment: thanks for the reply. but how about new directories? it seems that they won't be added automatically.

Answer (score 12):

The `svn add` and `git add` commands do different things. The `git add` command is used to submit *any* change to any file (including new files) to the Git index, in preparation for a subsequent commit.

The `svn add` command is *only* used to add new files to the repository, when preparing for a commit. Changed files are submitted using the `svn commit` command, and do not need to be added first.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem when copying multiple files of when creating a bunch of new ones. Although svn is different to git the closest thing to `git add .` is `svn add * --force`

For example if you had a directory with a bunch of new files and you were in the parent directory just run this:

```
$ svn add * --force
A      new/dir
A      new/dir/newfile1
A      new/dir/newfile2
...
```

Answer (score -3):

[svn import](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/fr/svn-book.html#svn.tour.importing.import)
svn documentation here.